# Type.GetType() null in Console App

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work with Type.GetType() in a console app with code that goes like this:

```
    private static string RevokeApp(string app)
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType("Factory.App1");
        MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Revoke", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var result = method.Invoke(null, null);
        return result.ToString(); ;
    }
```

t returns null in all the ways I've tried.  I suspect the type's name is where my problem is. I've found advice pertaining to code that builds to a dll but my code builds to an exe and What I've tried  - assembly-specific naming etc. - doesn't seem to be working.

Namespace = "ConsoleApplication3"

Any help, advice or derisive. peals of laughter will be welcome

Comment: Can you post the complete code for `Factory.App1`?

Comment: Can you post the code of Factory.App1 class also?

Comment: You need an assembly-qualified name, as `GetType` only searches the currently executing assembly and mscorlib.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Know your assembly path.
var assembly= Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\myDll.dll");
        Type type = assembly.GetType("Factory.App1");
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```